# How to make a table and access table parameters using array of structures in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

Rows are Temperature and columns are Pressure.

```
Temp   750   755  760   765(pressure)

0      1.1   2     1     4
1       3    4     2     1  (factors)
2       4    5     5     9
```

I need a help in making this table in code with that i would like to access factor values for respective temp and pressure .

For example if temp 0 and pressure 750 the factor value is 1.1 ,if temp 1 and pressure 750 factor value is 3.

[My Sample Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrUW2.jpg)

Comment: One simple solution will be using a 2D array for factor data and 2 1D arrays for temperature and pressure value. Then relating all coloms and rows to respective temp and pressure values.

Comment: Thank you ,can you please explain me with code

Comment: Upendra, for code, see, for example, https://helloacm.com/cc-function-to-compute-the-bilinear-interpolation/ Or just google "bilinear interpolation" or "two-dimensional interpolation" or anything like that for many more examples. I believe you're going to want a function something like **double factor(double temp, double pressure)** that finds the four-point grid surrounding the input temp,pressure and interpolates between those points back to the input values. If you're talking about an ideal gas, then you probably want linear interpolation. Otherwise, depends on what you're dealing with.

Comment: Thank you john,can anyone help me to solve this using arrays or array of structures in c programming .

Comment: @Upendra, this site for solving particular problems faced while programming or giving directions, not for solving homework problems.

Comment: @Sma ,yes i know and i am asking for guidelines to implement it .thank you

Comment: @Sma, Could you please explain me this ?

Comment: @Upendra, 1 approach can be storing all the factor value in `NxM` 2D `float/double` matrix, where N and M are number of Temp and pressure values respectively. Then next step is storing all these Temp and pressure vaules (axis) in seperate 1D `int/float` matrix. Now during search match the value of temp and pressure in their respective matrix. The index of both searches will be the final index in factor matrix.